# Request.UrlReferrer is NULL for HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

I am using `"Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri"` in my project to get the URL where my application is hosted. I am able to get the URL, if I am redirected from "http" host, but I am getting null, if I am redirected from "https" host. how can I get `"UrlReferrer AbsoluteUri"` of both "http and https"?

Answer (score 7):

Check the actual http data using a https-aware inspector like fiddler. Many browsers simply *don't send the referrer* when communicating over https, in which case there is simply *no way to get it*.

If you *own* the origin site, you could add something into the query-string as a substitute, but that's about it.

Comment: @Aron well, that depends what it is meant to be secure *from*, and most commonly that means: preventing inspection by anyone other than the target, and having confidence that the server is who it says it is. The http-referrer does not impact on that. Privacy of *where they came from* isn't really related to https, and is more akin to "incognito mode", "in private browsing", or whatever any particular browser calls that feature. But: if they want to include it when using https: fine

Comment: Ah good good. Yes. Security is a word that only make sense in context of what you are securing against. But however the problem is...outside of the Tech world (and even within a HUGE proportion of the tech world), people use the word secure as some magical boolean state. Hence I think browsers tend to be on the safe side when using HTTPS.