# Request.UrlReferrer for external links C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

A page on website X has a link(which is a target=_blank) to website Y's home page.

On website Y's home page, can we see if the user is coming from website X and if they are, we need to redirect to a different page on website Y.

Is this possible?

Will Request.UrlReferrer work in this context? I tried it on my local machine, it is not working.

The page on website Y is on https, where as the page on website X is http.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you website y or website x?  If you're website Y you should have access to the referrer (save some scenarios like HTTPs, purposefully stripping it out, etc)... but I'm unclear from your question where you fit into this whole scenario.

Comment: I have access to website Y.  In short what I am looking for is https://websitex.com has an external link to our website(websitey.com/default.aspx). So, what we are trying to do is to redirect to a different page if they are coming from https://websitex.com. Thanks.

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629513/request-urlreferrer-is-null-for-https It explains why the `Request.UrlReferrer` is null for you.

Comment: oh.. thanks.. makes sense.. any suggestions to overcome this issue?

Comment: If it is from HTTPS to HTTPS, will it work?